# Count vowels in a string

Tags: python, string, count

I want to count the vowels (`a, e, i, o, u`) in a given string.

Example:

```
count vowels in `ajdgejfifhou`
```

Should provide: `5`

How can I achieve this using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this

```
def numVowels(a):
    vowels = "aeuioAEUIO"
    result = 0
    for char in a:
        if char in vowels:
            result = result + 1
    return result

numVowels("ajdgejfifhou")
```